# Installing LaTeX into Google's Debian8 docker image

Tags: debian, docker, latex

I'm trying to figure out how to install LaTeX (specifically, [this texlive package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/texlive)) into Google's Debian8 Docker image, which is called `gcr.io/google-appengine/debian8`. I wish I could provide a link to that, but I can't find it on Docker or on GitHub. Actually, I'm using [this image](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/blob/master/runtime-base/Dockerfile.template) which derives indirectly from it.

If I try and install it into the image I get an error:

```
> apt-get install texlive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package texlive
```

I suspect I need to add an appropriate source (and possibly key) to the apt sources, but I have no idea how to figure out what exactly. I believe I'd end up with a Docker command along the lines of this (but likely simpler):

```
RUN \
  apt-get -q update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q curl git ca-certificates apt-transport-https openssh-client && \
  curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
  curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list && \
  curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_unstable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_unstable.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install dart=$DART_VERSION-1 && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? How do I determine what needs to be added to `/etc/apt/sources` to make the `texlive` package show up?

Comment: What makes you think that google/dart is based on debian8? I can't find this. It seems poorly documented.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor this does: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/blob/master/base/Dockerfile.template#L4

Comment: I pulled `google-appengine/debian8` with docker, run a terminal, did a `apt search`. `textlive` package is in the repo. Did you run `apt update` before calling `apt-get install texlive`?

Comment: Did you check your `sources.list` right after installation? How does it look like now? Must it be a google image or did you just choose randomly?

Comment: Do you have a line like `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main` in your `sources.list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example with **docker** on **macos 10.14 **, you start the image with bash.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ em$ docker run -it gcr.io/google-appengine/debian8 /bin/bash
```

You try to install **textlive**

```
root@6b616ce25c70:/# apt-get install -d  texlive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package texlive
```

The image provided by Google is stripped, so many temporary files are removed.

So you must run **apt-get update**

```
root@6b616ce25c70:/# apt-get update
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.0 kB]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [818 kB]
Get:7 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.3 MB in 9s (1132 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Now you  can run  **apt-get install texlive**

```
root@6b616ce25c70:/# apt-get install -d  texlive
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp cpp-4.9 dbus file fontconfig fontconfig-config 
  .../...
Suggested packages:
  cpp-doc gcc-4.9-locales dbus-x11 ghostscript-x apache2 
  ../..  
Recommended packages:
  libarchive-tar-perl wish
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp cpp-4.9 dbus file fontconfig 
  ../..  
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-4.9-base libgcc1 libstdc++6
3 upgraded, 253 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 441 MB of archives.
After this operation, 897 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm glad it was this simple a problem, if a little embarrassed that I didn't think of that.

Comment: You should probably create a docker file with a `run apt-get update; apt-get install -d  texlive`. Doing it interactively, puts it into the ephemeral layer. It will be lost when you remove the container. (Or you can do it interactively, and save the layer, but is better to automate).